# How to create local folder for program data on Windows (in %APPDATA%, without granting permissions, JAVA)

Tags: java, windows, directory, path

How to create local folder for local program data in Java on Windows (in %APPDATA%, without granting windows permissions, I use JAVA)

I tried this code but file.mkdirs() doesnt create folder which indicates that I dont have permission to this folder

new File("%APPDATA%/PackMe/some_folder");

Ok found solution:
`System.getProperty("user.home") + "/PackMe/somefolder";`

Answer (score 2):

I think the appdata folder is this:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\PackMe\\somefolder";
```

or using the environment variable (which helped me when I encountered this problem too):

```
System.getenv("APPDATA");
```

Could you provide your full code and the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I dont have exception, just lFile.exists() return true (folder not exists) and lFile.canRead() return false

Comment: have you called mkdirs() to your created File object? Please provide your full code so I can reproduce the scenario:)

Comment: sure, but there were problems with permissions, it worked for me (win7):
`System.getProperty("user.home") + "/PackMe/somefolder";`

Comment: almost, but helped a lot, catch +1 :)

Comment: great to hear. I changed my answer to macht your path